# Select a treenode from Child of Child Node

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, treeview

I have below tree view and want to select child of child nodes:

- Class

  - Section A

    - Group A1
    - Group A2
  - Section B

    - Group B1
    - Group B2

I want to select node Group B2. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to do something like

```
TreeNode nodeSectionB = this.TreeView.Nodes["Section B"]; // Or .Nodes[1];
TreeNode node = nodeSectionB.Nodes["Group B2"]; // Or .Nodes[1];
this.TreeView.SelectedNode = node;
```

Note, that when using strings to reference nodes, it is assumed that you have provided a reference to do so. Otherwise you will have to use the node indexes. The above assumes that the tree is static and the poistions of the node your after does not change.

If the tree is dynamic, that is the position of the required node does change, you may have to loop though the tree to find the required node. To do this use something like

```
private void SelectTreeNode(TreeView treeView, string nodeText)
{
    TreeNodeCollection nodes = treeView.Nodes;
    foreach (TreeNode n in nodes)
        CheckRecursive(n, nodeText);
}

private void CheckRecursive(TreeNode treeNode, string nodeText)
{
    foreach (TreeNode tn in treeNode.Nodes)
        if (String.Compare(tn.Text, nodeText, true) == 0)
            this.TreeView.SelectedNode = tn;
}
```

where it is assumed the `this.TreeView` is an accessor for your tree view. `nodeText` here is the required node text to find - this may have to be ammended for nodes with the same textual values.

I hope this helps.